# PHP MySQL Update Query not working with vars

Tags: php, mysql

```
$ID = trim($_GET["uid"]);
$Name = trim($_GET["name"]);

$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `Benutzer` SET `R_NAME`='$Name' WHERE `ID` = '$ID'");
```

The Result returns fine, but the Database is not updated. If I replace the vars with static values the Database IS updated.

Comment: echo your $ID and $Name variable and check if they contain some value??

Comment: @Ankit I don't see why that would make a difference

Comment: @CMX you need to use mysqli_real_escape_string to escape your parameters, or use prepared statements. You're open to SQL Injection otherwise.

Comment: They do contain the correct values.

Comment: Print the query before you execute it. And try to run it manually. You'll easily find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Remove "trim" & use "mysql_escape_string".
2. Echo Check the values of Name & ID. Once you are getting them then follow up   with the 3rd step.
3. Concatinate the sql string as shown by removing the tild operators:

   `$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE Benutzer SET R_NAME ='".$Name."' WHERE ID =   '".$ID."'");`

Comment: Prepare statement is much better because of the security it provides out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Use mysqli prepare statement.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Benutzer SET R_NAME = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param($Name,$ID);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score -2):

What we pass in the query arguments is a string or we can say query in the form of string. you can change the query like below.

`` $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `Benutzer` SET `R_NAME`='".$Name."' WHERE `ID` = '".$ID."'"); ``

Comment: Thanks  ivan for the change. new to stack

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) how to format your posts and try to not post answers with all capital case or bolded. Thanks.